# Returning array of elements whose indexes are specified in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to return array of elements whose indexes are specified in another array.

```
>>> a = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]
>>> ar = np.array(a)
>>> p=[0,0]
>>> pr = np.array(p)
>>> ar[:,pr[:]]
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[5, 6],
        [5, 6]]])
```

I understand why the output came. It simply returned 0th element in each 0th (outermost) dimension of `ar` two times, since `p=[0,0]`. What I want is it should index 0th dimension of `ar` using indexes specified inside `pr`.

So, above should return

```
[[1,2],[5,6]]
```

So here, we used `p[0]` (which is `0`) to index inside `ar[0]` returning `[1,2]` and `p[1]` (which is also `0`) to index inside index inside `ar[1]` returning `[5,6]`.

Similarly I want following outputs:

- For `p=[0,1]`, I want `[[1,2],[7,8]]`
- For `p=[1,0]`, I want `[[3,4],[5,6]]`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
>>> ar[np.indices(ar.shape[:1]), pr]
array([[[1, 2],
        [5, 6]]])
```

Note, `np.indices` simply returns an array of indices of a given shape, in this case:

```
>>> np.indices(ar.shape[:1])
array([[0, 1]])
```

Maybe, squeeze it:

```
>>> ar[np.indices(ar.shape[:1]), pr].squeeze()
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

Or maybe use `arange`:

```
>>> ar[np.arange(ar.shape[0]), pr]
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: so what the difference it make in changing first index of `ar[?,pr]` from `?=:` to `?=np.arrange(..)` or `?=np.indices(..)`? It indexes into individial element of `ar`, but in individual element, shouldnt it use both indices of `pr`?